# Proper way to handle a group of asynchronous calls in parallel

Tags: c#, parallel-processing, async-await, task

I have a console app that calls a web api and gets a list of services.  It then loops through and makes calls to each service.

I have the following:

```
static int Main(string[] args)
{
   ...       
   Task.WaitAll(Process());
}

private static async Task BeginProcess()
{
   using(HttpClientHandler handler = new HttpClientHandler())
   {
      handler.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
      using(var client = new HttpClient(handler))
      {
         var response = client.GetStringAsync(_baseUrl);

         List<Service> services = new List<Service>();
         services = jss.Deserialize<List<Service>>(response.Result);

         client.Timeout = new TimeSpan(0,3,0);
         foreach(var service in services)
         {
            Console.WriteLine("Running " + service.Name);
            var _serviceResponse = await client.PostAsync(_baseURL + service.Id.ToString(), null);
            Console.WriteLine(service.Name + " responded with " + _serviceRepsonse.StatusCode);
         }
      }
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, this code processes each service sequentially rather than making the calls in parallel.  The problem is, I'm not sure how to make these calls run in parallel.

Comment: You need to replace your loop with `await Task.WhenAll()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While I've accepted an answer, I finally landed on this which I felt was more succinct.

```
await Task.WhenAll(services.Select(async s => {
   Console.WriteLine("Running " + s.Name);
   var _serviceResponse = await client.PostAsync(...);
   Console.WriteLine(s.Name + " responded with " + _serviceResponse.StatusCode);
}));
```

Comment: Do me a favor and mark this as the official answer.  This code is much nicer than my answer.

Answer (score 3):

The answer can be found in Concurrency in C# cookbook :

```
static async Task<string> DownloadAllAsync(IEnumerable<string> urls){
    var httpClient = new HttpClient();

    var downloads = urls.select(url => httpClient.getStringAsync(url));
    Task<string>[] tasks = downloads.ToArray(); //-> tasks are started
    //now that you have an array of tasks you can wait for them all to finish
    string[] htmlPages = await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
    return string.Concat(htmlPages); 
}
```

The key points here are :

- arrange the code to obtain an array of tasks (different containers are also ok, it does not have to be an array)
- use await Task.WhenAll(array of tasks);

Answer (score 1):

as @SLaks mentioned, you will need to replace your loop with something along these lines...

```
     var asyncTasks = new Dictionary<Service, Task>();
     foreach(var service in services)
     {
        Console.WriteLine("Running " + service.Name);
       asyncTasks.Add(service, client.PostAsync(_baseURL + service.Id.ToString(), null));
     }
     // All tasks are running, so wait for all of them to finish here
     await Task.WhenAll(asyncTasks);

     foreach(var service in asyncTasks.Keys) {
        Console.WriteLine("Service " + service.Name + " returned " + syncTasks[service].Result);
     }
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: The problem with the above code is that I lose the ability to reference the service when I have the result.  If you notice my original code, I write to console the name of the service with the response code that was returned.

Comment: @RHarris yes, but you can easily replace my asyncTasks List into a dictionary where the service would be the key for example - that way you know exactly which task belongs to which service. I'll edit my answer to reflect that requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Change this:

```
foreach(var service in services)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Running " + service.Name);
    var _serviceResponse = await client.PostAsync(_baseURL + service.Id.ToString(), null);
    Console.WriteLine(service.Name + " responded with " + _serviceRepsonse.StatusCode);
}
```

to this:

```
var serviceCallTaskList = new List<Task<HttpResponseMessage>>();
foreach(var service in services)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Running " + service.Name);
    serviceCallTaskList.Add(client.PostAsync(_baseURL + service.Id.ToString(), null));
}

HttpResponseMessage[] responseArray = await Task.WhenAll(serviceCallTaskList);

for(int i = 0; i < responseArray.Length; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine(services[i].Name + " responded with " + responseArray[i].StatusCode);
}
```